# If $X,Y\sim N(0, σ^2)$ are independent, what is the conditional distribution of $X$ given $X+Y=12$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

> If $X,Y\sim N(0, σ^2)$ are independent, find the conditional distribution of $X$ given $X+Y=12$.

The answer is $X |_{X+Y =12} \sim N(6, σ^2/2)$. It seems not that hard but I couldn't get it right.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: **Hint:** The sum of two independent normally distributed random variables is ...

Answer (score 1):

You must evaluate:
$$f_{X\mid X+Y}(x\mid 12)=\dfrac{f_X(x)~f_Y(12-x)}{f_{X+Y}(12)}$$

Now since $X,Y$ are normally distributed, the numerator is easy: $$f_X(x)~f_Y(12-x)=(2\pi\sigma^2)^{-1/2}\exp(-x^2/(2\sigma^2))\cdot (2\pi\sigma^2)^{-1/2}\exp(-(12-x)^2/(2\sigma^2))$$

But what is the probability density function of $X+Y$ , the sum of two *independent* and *normally* distributed random variables?

Comment: Sum of two independent and normally distributed random variable is again normal distribution , i.e. $\mathcal{N}(0,2\sigma^2)$. To verify that we can use characteristic function.